# PHP - Replacing emoticon with meaning

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, str-replace, emoticons

I am analysing informal chat style message for sentiment and other information. I need all of the emoticons to be replaced with their actual meaning, to make it easier for the system to parse the message.

At the moment I have the following code:

```
$str = "Am I :) or :( today?";

$emoticons = array(
    ':)'    =>  'happy',
    ':]'    =>  'happy',
    ':('    =>  'sad',
    ':['    =>  'sad',
);

$str = str_replace(array_keys($emoticons), array_values($emoticons), $str);
```

This does a direct string replacement, and therefore does not take into account if the emoticon is surrounded by other characters.

How can I use regex and `preg_replace` to determine if it is actually an emoticon and not part of a string?

Also how can I extend my array so that `happy` element for example can contain both entries; `:)` and `:]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For maintainability and readability, I would change your emoticons array to:

```
$emoticons = array(
    'happy' => array( ':)', ':]'),
    'sad'   => array( ':(', ':[')
);
```

Then, you can form a look-up table just like you originally had, like this:

```
$emoticon_lookup = array();
foreach( $emoticons as $name => $values) {
    foreach( $values as $emoticon) {
        $emoticon_lookup[ $emoticon ] = $name;
    }
}
```

Now, you can dynamically form a regex from the emoticon lookup array. Note that this regex requires a non-word-boundary surrounding the emoticon, change it to what you need.

```
$escaped_emoticons = array_map( 'preg_quote', array_keys( $emoticon_lookup), array_fill( 0, count( $emoticon_lookup), '/'));
$regex = '/\B(' . implode( '|', $escaped_emoticons) . ')\B/';
```

And then use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) with a custom callback to implement the replacement:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback( $regex, function( $match) use( $emoticon_lookup) {
    return $emoticon_lookup[ $match[1] ];
}, $str);
```

You can see from [this demo](http://viper-7.com/VUdTK8) that this outputs:

```
Am I happy or sad today?
```